# Why does $dV=\rho^2\sin{\phi}\, d{\rho}\, d{\theta}\, d\phi$?

Tags: integration, spheres

I was watching [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4ULJBHGZpx4&ab_channel=MichelvanBiezen) from MichelvanBiezen wherein he explains how to find the volume of a hemisphere by setting $dV=\rho^2\sin{\phi}\, d{\rho}\, d{\theta}\, d\phi$. I understood everything in the video except for this first part, which he does not elaborate on. Could someone give an explanation or geometric intuition? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can either "visualize" an infitesimal volume element as in Yuriy's answer or consider a change of variables from cartesian coordinates to spherical coordinates, whose Jacobian is precisely the prefactor $\rho^2\sin\phi$.

Comment: @Abezhiko I'll look into that thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to visualize volume elements in spherical coordinates.

In Cartesian coordinates $dV$ is a small cube, which is why it's equal to $dxdydz$.

In spherical coordinates it's more complicated. But I'm pretty sure this picture will explain everything:

[image]

[Source of the diagram](https://calcworkshop.com/multiple-integrals/triple-integrals-in-spherical-coordinates/)

**Note:** Cartesian volume elements are not the same as spherical volume elements.

Comment: Neat tool, thanks for sharing!